# Is there a way to send a value from a unit test to another unit test?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a function which calculates some stuff and inputs it into a DB. This setup is important for all unit tests because they need some data to work on.

Sometimes i need to "flush" the DB, so all the unit tests point to the wrong ID.

Normally i just run the setup first and then change all the unit tests but this is taking to long tbh. **Is there a way to automate this?**

I would like to pass the generated ID into other unit tests.

So the idea was something like this:

```
[SetupFixture]
public class{
    [Test]
    public void SetupDB(){
        setup();

        //now marking the result somehow so other tests can pick the result up
        return ID; //<--
    }
}

public class OtherTests{
    [Test]
    [Get_ID_From_SetupDB]
    public void testBaseOnID(int ID){
        //we do stuff now with ID
    }
}
```

PS: i have no problem switching the testing framework if you know a framework which can do this

Comment: It's a bad Idea to make one test dependent on another.  
I suggest preparing and flushing data for each test.  
Test frameworks usually have an option for this. Nunit for example has the [SetUp] and [TearDown] attributes: http://nunit.org/docs/2.2.10/setup.html

Comment: If all your tests require some common data, prepare that data *before* the tests. This is usually done by something like a `SetupAttribute` or similar.

Comment: the problem is that setup() takes like 10 minutes to compile. I need to test if setup worked correctly and i need to test some basic functions on the DB.

Comment: "the problem is that setup() takes like 10 minutes to compile" Eeeehm, what? I doubt it takes 10 mnutes to *compile*, as the compiler doesn´t compile one member after the other making it impossible to determine which member takes whatever amount of time. Anyway you should ask why the setup even takes as much time, instead of trying to circumnvent the problem with an inapropriate solution, making this an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Putting your logic into another method won´t reduce its complexity.

Comment: Iam sorry yeah it needs 10 minutes to finish... i cant  make this faster since its an uploaddownload process

Comment: @rmrfhome Please don't send people to legacy documentation unless that's what they say they need! Current NUnit docs are at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki

Comment: @Charlie sorry, it was my mistake )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests should be independent and you should generally never pass values between tests.

What you can do in your case, if all the tests are in the same class, is to have a variable in your class to hold the id and some global setup function that sets everything up and sets the variable to the correct id. In NUnit there is the [OneTimeSetUp] atribute for that.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests 
{
private int _testId;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void SetItUp()
{
...
_testId = whatever;
}
[Test]
public void TestOne()
{
var whatever = _testId;
...
}
}
```